# Muting work email after working hours in outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I setup two emails accounts in microsoft outlook 2016 on my laptop; work email account and another personal one.

How can I mute the work email after the working hours (e.g. stop making the envelop appear in the task bar)?

Comment: What I do is to turn off Automatic Send/Receive in the lesser used email account and do a manual send receive regularly.  That works very well for me.

Comment: Thanks @John for your suggestion. Anyway, I don't find it effective as i might forget to press on send/receive during working. I am trying to find a solution based on a scheduler.

Comment: I have been using Outlook for many years and I have not seen a “half-daily” schedule method for Outlook. I do understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could try auto send/receive every 10 minutes for your main account and perhaps hourly for the work account. That may help you.

Comment: @John, ok could u plz post the way for that?

Comment: Why not use an alternative mail client like Thunderbird for one of your accounts?

Comment: @davidgo .. I tried it before but i didn't like it. outlook is way better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Outlook 2016, Send/Receive tab, pull down Send Receive Groups and then down near the bottom of the pull down, click on Define Send Receive Groups.

In the Dialog that comes up (Screen Shot below here), you can set up Groups.

Set up a Group for Work Mail and set up a Group for Your Mail.

In the dialogue Window, you can set Send / Receive properties and intervals for each different Group.

Set your group for every 10 minutes or so and set the Work Group for 60 minutes (or any interval that works for you).

[image]